# When I am adding list to the set function the order of my strings are getting changed , how can I keep my order intact?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, jupyter-notebook

input: a = ['AAB', 'CAA', 'ADA']

```
(set(a[2]))                                      //**output is** {'A', 'D'}
list(set(a[2]))                                  // **output is** ['D', 'A']
''.join(list(set(a[2])))                         //**output is** 'DA'
```

How can I keep my order of string intact when I am applying list function to set ?

Comment: what is `a`?  list?

Comment: You can't, sets are not ordered.

Comment: If you are using 3.7+, use `list(dict.fromkeys(a[2]))` instead of `list(set(a[2]))`. Dicts preserve insertion order from 3.7 and beyond.

Answer (score 1):

Sets are not ordered in Python.

Use [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) or just use a dict (which keeps the insertion order), ignoring the key (use some dummy object like `None` as a value).

In this example, the last line will always print `['y', 'x']` in that order.

```
d={}
d['y'] = None
d['x'] = None
print(list(d))
```

For your code, that would be `dict.fromkeys(a[2], None)`

(Dictionaries keep their insertion order in practice but unofficially from Python 3.6, and officially from Python 3.7 and on).